# Regex to match comma-separated AWS regions in Python

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services

My target string has multiple items, and I need to match and retrieve the value of the comma-separated AWS regions:

```
data = '''
appname=ivr
age=2years
region='us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c'
'''
```

I'd like to get the value for `regions` in the output as `'us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c'`.

I tried using this regex, but it works only for one value without comma:

```
'(af|il|ap|ca|eu|me|sa|us|cn|us-gov|us-iso|us-isob)-(central|north|.       (north(?:east|west))|south|south(?:east|west)|east|west)-\d{1}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an optional comma on the end of your regex and then make that a repeating group:

```
pat = r'((?:af|il|ap|ca|eu|me|sa|us|cn|us-gov|us-iso|us-isob)-(?:central|north(?:east|west)?|south(?:east|west)?|east|west)-\d+[a-z]?,?)+'

out = re.search(pat, data)
print(out.group())
```

Output:

```
us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to use the `csv` library to parse:

```py
import csv

data = """
appname=ivr
age=2years
region='us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c'
"""

reader = csv.reader(data.strip().splitlines(), delimiter="=", quotechar="'")
parsed = dict(reader)
print(parsed)
print(parsed['region'])
```

Output:

```
{'appname': 'ivr', 'age': '2years', 'region': 'us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c'}
us-east-1a,us-east-2a,us-east-1c
```

Notes

- The expression `data.strip().splitlines()` cleans up the data and split it into lines
- We feed those lines into a `csv.reader`, specifying the equal sign as the fields delimiter.
- Each line is broken into 2 fields, we then call `dict()` to turn them into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a little bit and came up with this regex expression you may try out:

```
us-[a-z]+-[^\r\n,']+
```